# xpath - find all last descandant hyperlinks within a list of items

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath

I have a dynamically generated page with a huge list which contains NESTED LINK ELEMENTS.

- Sometime the list items contain ONE hyperlink and sometimes they contain TWO hyperlinks.
- The depth/level of the nested links varies so it is different every time I refresh the page.
- **IMPORTANT:** Within each list item at least one link has a link text. **These are the links I want.**
- **BUT:** The parent element of the link text varies every time I refresh the page.

  ```
     <div class="listitem">
          <div>
               <a href="https://www.testpage/user1">
          </div>
          <div>
               <a href="https://www.testpage/user2">
                    <span>
                          <div>user2</div>
                    </span>
               </a>
          </div>
     </div>


     <div class="listitem">
          <div>
               <a href="https://www.testpage/user3">
                   <div>user3</div>
               </a>
          </div>
     </div>



     <div class="listitem">
          <div>
               <div>
                    <a href="https://www.testpage/user4">
                         <span>
                               <span>user4</span>
                         </span>
                    </a>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>


     <div class="listitem">
          <div>
               <div>
                    <div>
                         <a href="https://www.testpage/user5" />
                    </div> 
               </div>
               <div>
                    <a href="https://www.testpage/user6">
                         <div>
                               <div>user6</div>
                         </div>
                    </a>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
  ```

The result should be a list with user2, user3, user4 and user6

- I alredy tried  div/a[last()] but this returns ALL 6 hyperlinks
- And I tried (div/a)[last()] but this returns hyperlink 6 only

So my question is:

- Which xpath is needed to get the **LAST HYPERLINK-DESCENDANTS OF ALL FOUR ITEMS**.
- Or in other words: How to get the **HYPERLINKS WHERE THE HREF-ATRIBUTE EQUALS THE TEXT WITHIN THE LAST DESCENDANT ELEMENTS **

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you want to get all the links containing texts i.e links from `a` elements containing child element (`span` or `div`) containing texts.
If so you can use the following XPath:

```py
//div[@class='listitem']//a[@href and(text())]
```

If you want to get (and print) all these links with Selenium it can be done with the following loop:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='listitem']//a[@href and(text())]")))
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

`//a[@href and(text())]` means: element with `a` tag having `href` attribute (not specified the attribute value i.e. any value) and having a text (any text content)

Comment: Could you please explain the a[@href and(text())] ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer. Please let me know if now it is clear enough or you need more explanations

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<div class="listitem">
    <div>
         <a href="https://www.testpage/user1">
    </div>
    <div>
         <a href="https://www.testpage/user2">
              <span>
                    <div>user2</div>
              </span>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listitem">
    <div>
         <a href="https://www.testpage/user3">
             <div>user3</div>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listitem">
    <div>
         <div>
              <a href="https://www.testpage/user4">
                   <span>
                         <span>user4</span>
                   </span>
              </a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listitem">
    <div>
         <div>
              <div>
                   <a href="https://www.testpage/user5" />
              </div> 
         </div>
         <div>
              <a href="https://www.testpage/user6">
                   <div>
                         <div>user6</div>
                   </div>
              </a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To get the value of the `href` attributes of the second `<a>` elements having link text i.e. ***user2***, ***user3***, ***user4*** and ***user6***, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='listitem']/div//div//a[.//self::div[starts-with(., 'user')] or .//self::span[starts-with(., 'user')]]")))])
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```